# iPhone UIImageView and CABasicAnimation

Tags: iphone, cabasicanimation

I am doing a simple card rotation which works fine, but when I add a custom image background, after the card roation, the image is half chopped off.  Any ideas?

```
float scaleValue = M_PI/2;

CABasicAnimation *yRotation;
yRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
yRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
yRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:scaleValue];
yRotation.duration = .5;

CABasicAnimation *yRotation2;
yRotation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
yRotation2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:scaleValue];
yRotation2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
yRotation2.duration = .5;
yRotation2.cumulative = YES;
yRotation2.beginTime = .5;

CAAnimationGroup *groupAnim = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
groupAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
groupAnim.duration = 1;
groupAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
groupAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
groupAnim.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yRotation, yRotation2, nil];

[[image objectAtIndex:num] addAnimation:groupAnim forKey:@"animateCard"];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[image objectAtIndex:num]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is help to you .......

once try it will be perfectly working...without  choppedoff

```
  - (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

// Orbit #1
CALayer *orbit1 = [CALayer layer];
orbit1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
orbit1.position = self.view.center;
orbit1.cornerRadius = 100;
orbit1.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
orbit1.borderWidth = 1.5;

CALayer *planet1 = [CALayer layer];
planet1.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
planet1.position = CGPointMake(100, 0);
planet1.cornerRadius = 10;
planet1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[orbit1 addSublayer:planet1];

CABasicAnimation *anim1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
anim1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim1.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
anim1.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
anim1.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim1.duration = 8.0;
[orbit1 addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"transform"];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:orbit1];

// Orbit #2
CALayer *orbit2 = [CALayer layer];
orbit2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120);
orbit2.position = planet1.position;
orbit2.cornerRadius = 60;
orbit2.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
orbit2.borderWidth = 1.5;

CALayer *planet2 = [CALayer layer];
planet2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16);
planet2.position = CGPointMake(60, 0);
planet2.cornerRadius = 8;
planet2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
[orbit2 addSublayer:planet2];

CABasicAnimation *anim2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
anim2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
anim2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
anim2.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim2.duration = 4.0;
[orbit2 addAnimation:anim2 forKey:@"transform"];

[orbit1 addSublayer:orbit2];

// Orbit #3
CALayer *orbit3 = [CALayer layer];
orbit3.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 72);
orbit3.position = planet2.position;
orbit3.cornerRadius = 36;
orbit3.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
orbit3.borderWidth = 1.5;

CALayer *planet3 = [CALayer layer];
planet3.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 12, 12);
planet3.position = CGPointMake(36, 0);
planet3.cornerRadius = 6;
planet3.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
[orbit3 addSublayer:planet3];

CABasicAnimation *anim3 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
anim3.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim3.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
anim3.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
anim3.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim3.duration = 2.0;
[orbit3 addAnimation:anim3 forKey:@"transform"];

[orbit2 addSublayer:orbit3];
```